# Solve $[\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}]=\frac{x-1}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value, integers

How can one solve the equation :

$[\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}]=\frac{x-1}{3}$ ?

Such that $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

By definition :

$[\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}]<=\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}<[\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}]+1$.

So :

$\frac{x-1}{3}<=\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}<\frac{x-1}{3}+1$.

1)

$\frac{x-1}{3}<=\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}$ <=> $3x^2-5x+5>0$.

2)

$\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}<\frac{x-3}{2}+1$ <=> $3x^2-5x-1<0$.

How can I solve the system ?

Comment: Note that 1) is true for all $x$ since $b^2 - 4ac < 0$. So you just have to solve the second one.

Comment: A title that consists entirely of MathJax makes a question difficult for people to access from the list of questions. I have edited the title to help with this.

Comment: @Marconius Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the original equation as:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}\right\rfloor=\frac{x-1}{3} \tag{1}$$

By definition of the floor function, both sides of the equation must be integers, i.e. $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. So then $x^2-x+1$ is an odd integer, *whether $x$ is even or odd*. Therefore

$$\left\lfloor\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}\right\rfloor=\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{x^2-x}{2}$$

Substituting back into (1):

$$\frac{x^2-x}{2}=\frac{x-1}{3} \implies \frac{x(x-1)}{2}=\frac{x-1}{3} \implies x=\tfrac{2}{3}\text{ or }x=1$$

Of these $x=1$ is the only integer potential solution, and checking against (1) shows that it is a solution to the original equation.

Comment: Why did you write $\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: @user233658 - $\frac{x^2-x+1}{2}$ is an odd multiple of $\frac{1}{2}$, so has fractional part $\frac{1}{2}$, which is discarded by the floor function. This is the same as just subtracting $\frac{1}{2}$ from the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to recognize that the left hand side is, by definition of the floor function, an integer, so the right hand side must also be an integer, and hence we must have $x=3k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  This gives (on doing a little algebra)

$${x^2-x+1\over2}={3k(3k+1)\over2}+{1\over2}$$

Note that $2$ divides either $k$ or $3k+1$, so $3k(3k+1)/2$ in an integer for any $k$, hence

$$\big\lfloor{x^2-x+1\over2}\big\rfloor={3k(3k+1)\over2}$$

Thus the equation to solve (for integer $k$) is

$${3k(3k+1)\over2}=k$$

But the only integer solution is $k=0$, since $k\not=0$ implies $3(3k+1)=2$.  So $x=1$ is the only real solution to the original equation.